# trigger.io cannot find my device but eclipse device tab shows

Tags: trigger.io

I am a paying customer and clicked on support expecting a full blown knowledgebase/email submit form but it links directly to here.

anyhow, trigger.io cannot find my android device. I am able to build and develop android apps using eclipse ADT but trigger.io just can't seem to discover it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the same tool (`adb`) as eclipse to communicate with the Android device, but it can get confused. Do any of the following help?

- Close eclipse and try again, it may be holding a connection to the device open
- Unplug and plug the device in again
- Restart the device
- Restart your computer

If none of those help can you let us know what device/OS you are using and what the output you get is?

Also you can always email support@trigger.io for support, we use stackoverflow for support as often other people have encountered similar problems and may be able to help you out.

Comment: I actually think SO is a great way. I am using Samsung Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.1. I used to use Eclipse ADT to develop app directly on my phone but Trigger.io doesn't seem to be able to find it. I will have another attempt and will email for support if it doesn't work.